# Docker: Composer could not find a composer.json file in /app

Tags: php, laravel, docker, dockerfile, debian

Hi I've got problem with running Dockerfile on Debian S390x. When i use command:

```
docker build -t laravel .
```

I've got error information:

```
Composer could not find a composer.json file in /app
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file. See https://getcomposer.org/basic-usage
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.4
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y openssl zip unzip git
RUN apt-get install libonig-dev
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
RUN mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo mbstring
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN composer install

CMD php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8181
EXPOSE 8181
```

Please help

Image of the error :
[image]

Comment: Can you share the content of the directory where your `Dockerfile` lives ? the error obviously is  docker complaining of a missing `composer.json` file when running composer install.

Comment: root@zDEB:/home/test/Laravel# ls
Dockerfile

Comment: is there a `composer.json` file in the directory where you're copying `COPY . /app` ? it must be for example a valid laravel project. so it copies all the  files including `composer.json` etc

Comment: I get it i must put into my container composer.json file because i must install requirements for my project

Comment: Yeah i get it wrong i was thinking i will get clear container with laravel but i must put my app into this to run everything, thanks for help ;3

Comment: Also if you're working with Laravel 8 (latest)  i would recommend using `sail` read more here https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sail

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. What did you try to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score -1):

You are copying it to the wrong directory at:

```
COPY . /app
```

Because earlier you defined a workdir:

```
WORKDIR /app
```

The contents will now be copied into:

```
/app/app
```

So change the `COPY` to the current directory, because you are already in `/app`:

```
COPY . .
```

Comment: If the _destination_ of a `COPY` command is an absolute path, files will be copied there, ignoring `WORKDIR`; the same as if you `cp composer.json /app` on native Linux.  (The source is always relative to the build-context directory even if it looks like an absolute path, though.)